# Ember.js - filtered model change does not trigger a change in rendered template

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have an application that prints a list of reservations. There are 2 routes:

```
reservations.allReservations

reservations.newReservations
```

**The Problem:**

The allReservations route works fine. If reservations are deleted or added, it is reflected automatically on the page. However, the newReservations route does not get refreshed on changes - however if I reload the page the changes are there.

**The setup:**

The main difference between the two is the routes model field. For the allReservation route it is:

```
App.Reservations.all();
```

for the newReservation route it is:

```
App.Reservations.all().filterProperty('isNew',true);
```

The application models and data store is setup as in the [Ember.js version of the TodoMVC app](https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences).

Route:

```
App.ReservationsNewReservationsRoute = Em.Route.extend({

model: function(){
       return App.Reservation.all().filterProperty('isNew', true);
    },

    renderTemplate: function(){
       this.render('reservationList');
    },
});
```

Controller:

```
App.ReservationsNewReservationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    isEmpty: function() { 
        return this.get( 'length' ) == 0;
    }.property( '@each.length', '@each.isNew'),

});
```

Template reservationList.hbs:

```
{{#if isEmpty}}
    <li>
        <div class="text-center" style="height: 40px; margin: auto 0;">
            <label>No Reservations!</label>
        </div>
    </li>
{{/if}}
{{#each controller}}
   ... print reservations ...
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a filtered array, I think you must use

```
model: function(){
   return App.Reservations.filter(function(reservation){
     return reservation.get('isNew') === true;
   });
});
```

which returns a live FilteredRecordArray, updated when there is a new reservation loaded in the store.

When you use filterProperty(), you loose the FilteredRecordArray, and then the resulted array is not live.

Since you're not using ember-data, you have to manually maintain the filter. I think there could be to way of doing this.

The simplest would be to add a computed property on the controller, which would return the filtered content, and populating the model with `App.reservations.all()`
Obviously in the template, you will use `{{#each controller.filteredContent}}` 
Something like:

```
App.ReservationsNewReservationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  isEmpty: function() { 
    return this.get( 'filtered.length' ) == 0;
  }.property('filtered.length'),

  //will be evaluated each time a reservation is added/removed, 
  //or each time a reservation's isNew property changed.
  filteredContent: function(){
     return this.get('content').filterProperty('isNew', true);
  }.property('@each.isNew')
});
```

The other solution could be to add the filter method on the Reservation model, and consistently in the store.

Comment: oh, sorry, seeing the all() method, I was assuming you were using ember-data. I must remove the tag I added by mistake. I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: I changed it to the following: App.Reservation.all().filter(... and I get no errors this time, but still no updates..

Comment: yeah, it's normal, because App.Reservation.all().filter() does not return a live array neither.

Comment: How would the template need to change to be work with your proposed filteredContent? Also, any insights on how I could a filter method on the Reservation model & store?

Comment: You have to use {{#each controller.filteredContent}} in the template, it should work. I think one naive implementation of filter in the store could be a computed property, like filteredContent here, but depending on `_all.@each`

Comment: Went with 'filteredContent' approach, works like a charm. Merci !